# Excel replacement of numbers with names

Tags: excel

I want to replace some specific numbers (repetitive and they are customer and vendor numbers) with their corresponding names (so as to be easily understood in a pivot table).

Eg in the next column to place a function that reverts the name of the number.

With which function can I do that?

Comment: The names of numbers are not generally regarded as being easier to read than the numbers themselves.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means the name that is associated to this number, not the written description of the number. For example, 12345 would be `Customer ABC inc.` not `Twelve thousand three hundred and forty five`

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional column of data with a VLOOKUP function which will populate the name of customers or vendors. For example, in your data sheet you could have:

`=VLOOKUP(A2, customers!A2:B100, 2, 0)`

This would lookup the value of A2 (say, the customer number) into the range A2:B100 of `customers` sheet (supposing the data in this sheet is customer number in A and customer description in B) and then return the appropriate customer name. Then just edit your pivot table data source to include that column and use it instead of the customer number.